For some reason, my code is not outputting anything
I'm trying to work on this assignment:
Design and implement a recursive program that solves the Non-Attacking Queens
problem. That is, write a program to determine all ways in which eight queens
can be positioned on an eight-by-eight chessboard so that none of them are in the
same row, column, or diagonal as any other queen. There are no other chess pieces
on the board.
Store your solutions in an array of strings, giving them the format:

. . . . q . . .
. q . . . . . .
. . . q . . . .
. . . . . . q .
. . q . . . . .
. . . . . . . q
. . . . . q . .
q . . . . . . .


Where "." represents a space with no queen and "q" represents a space with
a queen (there is a space between each set of adjacent characters).
Sort the array, and then print every solution in order, putting a line of
whitespace in between them.
I have some code written up for it but for some reason, no matter what I'm changing, nothing seems to be fixing the issue.
Here is the code:
import java.util.Arrays;

public class EightQueens {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] solutions = new String[92]; // 92 solutions for 8 queens on an 8x8 board
        solveQueens(0, new int[8], solutions);
        Arrays.sort(solutions);
        for (String solution : solutions) {
            System.out.println(solution);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void solveQueens(int row, int[] columns, String[] solutions) {
        if (row == 8) { // found a solution
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                    sb.append(columns[i] == j ? "q " : ". ");
                }
                sb.append("\n");
            }
            solutions[Arrays.binarySearch(solutions, sb.toString()) * -1 - 1] = sb.toString();
        } else {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                columns[row] = col;
                if (isValid(row, columns)) {
                    solveQueens(row + 1, columns, solutions);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isValid(int row, int[] columns) {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            int diff = Math.abs(columns[i] - columns[row]);
            if (diff == 0 || diff == row - i) {
                return false; // same column or diagonal
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

I have rewritten the code and changed things around but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Yes, I am. Arrays.sort(solutions):, Arrays.binarySearch(solutions, sb.toString()):, isValid(row, columns):
(Apologies if I'm not that coherent In my response. I have been hammering at this issue for hours and I am extremely tired)

It can help if you write some code comments for the methods solveQueens and the isValid (that is explain what those methods do in plain English). Have you looked at this for any help to solve the problem:  Eight Queens Puzzle - WIkipedia.

well, executing that code ends up throwing an NullPointerException: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Comparable.compareTo(Object)" because "midVal" is null - that is the reason why there is no output - somehow that information is MISSING IN THE QUESTION! Trying binarySearch on an array with some null elements! (maybe better to use a List or even a SortedSet instead of an array to store the results)

This problem has been asked and answered many times already. Here are the results of my search. Or simply try Googling for Java 8 queens recursion.

I assume that you're not allowed to use Lists...

Does this answer your question? NullPointerException with Java array - 8 queens

You can try this out..
here is the code
import java.util.Arrays;

public class EightQueens {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] solutions = new String[92]; // 92 solutions for 8 queens on an 8x8 board
        solveQueens(0, new int[8], solutions);
        Arrays.sort(solutions);
        for (String solution : solutions) {
            System.out.println(solution);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void solveQueens(int row, int[] columns, String[] solutions) {
        if (row == 8) { // found a solution
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                    sb.append(columns[i] == j ? "q " : ". ");
                }
                sb.append("\n");
            }
            addSolution(solutions, sb.toString());
        } else {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                columns[row] = col;
                if (isValid(row, columns)) {
                    solveQueens(row + 1, columns, solutions);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void addSolution(String[] solutions, String newSolution) {
        for (int i = 0; i < solutions.length; i++) {
            if (solutions[i] == null) {
                solutions[i] = newSolution;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isValid(int row, int[] columns) {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            int diff = Math.abs(columns[i] - columns[row]);
            if (diff == 0 || diff == row - i) {
                return false; // same column or diagonal
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}


When you give an answer you should explain what you've fixed instead of just providing code. eg. You were doing this wrong, . I fixed it and it seems to work.

Yes. I still don't get why the solutions array is sorted though (even if binarySearch is not used)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
